# How to append to a dataframe when using .apply function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to append a dataframe M to an empty dataframe Linked_df each time the duration is less than  11 seconds.
The following code appends a dataframe:

```
Linked_df=pd.DataFrame()
Linked=pd.DataFrame()
#for each unique date
for unq_date in Unique_Dates:
    #obtain dataframe of Mi and Ri of a specific date
    #add a column for index to track orignal index
    M=Mi.loc[(pd.to_datetime(Mi['EventDate']) == unq_date) ]
    R=Ri.loc[(pd.to_datetime(Ri['EventDate']) == unq_date) ]
    #Check if unique date exist in M
    Linked_df = R.apply(lambda row: create_dur(row['start_DateTime'], M,Linked_df), axis=1)
    Linked=Linked.append(Linked_df,ignore_index=True)
```

The function called and appends M to dataframe Linked_df :

```
def create_dur(row,M,Linked_df):
    M['duration']=(M['Event Read Time'] - row).dt.total_seconds()
    M.loc[M.duration < 0, 'duration'] = (row-M['Event Read Time']).dt.total_seconds()
    M=M.loc[M.duration < 11]
    #print(M['duration'])
    #print(M)
    row1 = pd.DataFrame(M)
    #Linked_df=pd.concat([Linked_df, row1], ignore_index=True)
    Linked_df=Linked_df.append(M,ignore_index=True)
    print(Linked_df)
    return Linked_df
```

The output from the function:

```
    EventDate             Id_str EventTime     Event Read Time       lat  \
0  2017-11-09  72057594042646832  01:13:24 2017-11-09 01:13:24 -27.73409   
1  2017-11-09  72057594042646832  01:13:29 2017-11-09 01:13:29 -27.73200   
2  2017-11-09  72057594042646848  01:13:30 2017-11-09 01:13:30 -27.73192   
3  2017-11-09  72057594042646864  01:13:32 2017-11-09 01:13:32 -27.73399   
4  2017-11-09  72057594042646880  01:13:33 2017-11-09 01:13:33 -27.73398   

       long  Speed  Sprung Weight  Frame Torque  ind_val_Mi  duration  
0  22.96531    9.0          468.0          88.0            101995       6.0  
1  22.97351   36.0          280.0          -4.0            101996       1.0  
2  22.97347   36.0          270.0         -10.0            101997       0.0  
3  22.96537    0.0          480.0          85.0            101998       2.0  
4  22.96537    2.0          489.0          89.0            101999       3.0  
    EventDate             Id_str EventTime     Event Read Time       lat  \
0  2017-11-09  72057594042646832  01:13:29 2017-11-09 01:13:29 -27.73200   
1  2017-11-09  72057594042646848  01:13:30 2017-11-09 01:13:30 -27.73192   
2  2017-11-09  72057594042646864  01:13:32 2017-11-09 01:13:32 -27.73399   
3  2017-11-09  72057594042646880  01:13:33 2017-11-09 01:13:33 -27.73398
```

The results are not being appended to the empty dataframe. It seems to update the dataframe. what is the cause?I have tried concat but get an empty list.

Comment: Can you validate if "R" is sometimes filled? If R is empty, R.apply(... is empty, too.

Comment: I have also tried this Linked_df=pd.concat([Linked_df, R.apply(lambda row: create_dur(row['start_DateTime'], M), axis=1)], ignore_index=True)
    print(Linked_df). It still doesnt work.

Comment: R is always filled.

Comment: Is there a way to save the dataframe it printed in the function? If apply function cant do it is there another function?

Comment: In a similar scenario I collected/appended each dataframe into a normal python list and used a pd.concat on that list at the end (outside of the function). This greatly improved the speed and at the same time allowed me to see all parts of the result after a function  run. Maybe this idea helps you.

Comment: Did you use apply funct?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Is this what you referring to t = R.apply(lambda row: pd.concat([Linked_df,create_dur(row['start_DateTime'], M)], ignore_index=True), axis=1)?

Comment: the output is empty.